# SSRS 2008 Wont return the correct Dataset from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I've got a Procedure which has multiple Query's which run depending on which Parameters are used.

```
If Reportname = 'Foo'
Begin
Select Forename, Surname, Jobtitle, Gender from Staff where X = y
End

If ReportName = 'Bar'
Begin
Select EnrolmentID, StudentID, EnrolmentStartDate, EnrollmentExpectedEndDate, Status  from Enrolment where y = Z
End
```

If I run this in SSMS it returns the correct records and columns. 
Where as in SSRS when I select the Procedure and set up the parameters, it defines the available columns as those contained within the first Select Statement of the Procedure.

This procedure is going to be used for various different reports and for backend processing, I ideally don't want to double up the code.

Has anyone got any recommendations on how to get SSRS to detect the correct context that's being applied?

I know I can alter some of the core logic to be in a table valued function which returns some universal data which applies to all circumstances.

Thanks

Also does anyone have tips on convincing my bosses to upgrade from ADO Classic to ADO.Net Entity Framework? I miss the flexibility of EF especially as we do everything in stored procedures, including returning single values which drives me mad.

Comment: You have 2 SPs with 2 different result sets => you have 2 reports. The design of those 2 reports is the same?

Comment: It's a single Procedure, which has multiple possible result sets which are parameter dependant. Each of the reports is going to be styled differently.

Comment: Regarding ADO.NET, I would propose a solution in which your COM component to call a separate .NET component based on Enterprise Library. As arguments, you have only one: monetize the advantages, transform them in gained hours on month and then put in figures.

Comment: The custom ADO Classic wrapper we're using is to force us to use Procedures It's so frustrating! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create 2 SPs each of them returning data for your 2 cases, then your "facade" SP set as source of your report could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ReportTable(col1 ID, col2 varchar(80), etc)
IF Reportname = 'Foo'
Begin
    INSERT #ReportTable(col1, col2, ...)
    EXEC dbo.GetDataForReport1 '7131', 25
End

IF ReportName = 'Bar'
Begin
    INSERT #ReportTable (col1, col2, ...)
    EXEC dbo.GetDataForReport2 '7131', 25
End

SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM #ReportTable
```

Comment: Thanks! This is one of those Doh! why didn't I think of that moments! it will get cluttered when we add more report sections. I'll go and have a play! :)